# Automatic maze solution

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

So I'm creating a maze app(I read from string-array the maze, and after that with touch events guide a ball trough it) . Managed to create everything so far, the app works fine. But I want to include an option to solve it automatically.

I'm using this recursive algorithm found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm

Basically I get the path in a boolean multi dimensional array (that has the size of the labyrinth).

Tried to achieve an MWC like design, so I have the following classes:

LabyrinthView - handles everything related to drawing the maze, and drawing the ball
LabyrinthModel - initialize the maze, handles ball movement, also I check here the end of the maze, and implemented recursiveSolve here to
LabyrinthActivity - this is where I bring everything together

Like I said so far solving the maze manually works like a charm.
Don't know how to animate the automatic solution.
So let me give you a maze example:

```
<string-array name="labyrinthEasy">
    <item>0000000001</item>
    <item>0111110110</item>
    <item>0100000110</item>
    <item>0101111000</item>
    <item>0101000010</item>
    <item>0101011010</item>
    <item>0101011110</item>
    <item>0101000010</item>
    <item>0101111010</item>
    <item>0100000010</item>
    <item>0111111110</item>
    <item>1000000000</item>
</string-array>
```

It will look something like this(E-Entry, F-finish):

[image]

And the solution:

[image]

This is how far I got so far:

```
private void selectControlMode() {
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Human","Machine"};
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
                case 0:
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    boolean temp;
                    temp = labyrinthModel.solveMaze();
                    if(temp){
                        new MazeSolver().execute();
                    }else{
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                        builder.setMessage("The maze is unsolvable!");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                switch (which) {
                                    case 0:
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(LabyrinthActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                        startActivity(intent1);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Basically I choose between human and machine solving from a dialog. If human is selected dispose the dialog and the nothing ( the app continues and waits for the manual solution). If machine is selected I get the path and if it can be solved I think I should start a new Thread here where I can animate the automatic solution, otherwise if it can't be solved I return to the main menu of the app. Now here starts my problem since I don't really know how to implement this in my AsyncTask class.

I do the logic in the doInBackgroung method, but can't figure out the logic how to follow the correct path. Because if I iterate trough the array row by row the ball will jump from row to row, and won't follow the fluidity of the path.
Also I think I should redraw my progress after each iteration using the onProgressUpdate method.

This is how my manual logic works (movement and drawing):

```
    labyrinthView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        float x1 = 0, x2 = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 0;
        float dx, dy;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float MIN_DIST = 5;
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    y1 = event.getY();
                    break;
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    y2 = event.getY();
                    dx = x2-x1;
                    dy = y2-y1;
                    Log.v("log", dx + " " + dy);
                    if(Math.abs(dx) > MIN_DIST || Math.abs(dy) > MIN_DIST){
                        if (Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy)){
                            if(dx > 0) {
                                labyrinthModel.right();
                                finishMessage();
                            }
                            else {
                                labyrinthModel.left();
                                finishMessage();
                            }
                        }else{
                            if(dy > 0) {
                                labyrinthModel.down();
                                finishMessage();
                            }
                            else {
                                labyrinthModel.up();
                                finishMessage();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            labyrinthView.invalidate();
            return true;
        }


    });
```

And this is what I have done so far in my assync task:

```
private class MazeSolver extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for ( int row = 0; row < labyrinthModel.correctPath.length; row ++)
            for ( int col = 0; col < labyrinthModel.correctPath[0].length; col++ ){
                if(labyrinthModel.correctPath[row][col + 1]){
                    labyrinthModel.moveRight();
                }
//here to do the implementaion of the path following logic???

            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
// here to redraw the progress ????
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

If you can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you are allowed to overwrite the path signaling two dimensional array you just need to follow the root from start to the end:

```
travel(correctPath, 0, 0, 11, 8);

void travel(bool a[][], int row, int col, int finalRow, int finalCol) {
   // if we are already there stop
   if(finalRow == row && col == finalCol) return;

   // avoid comming back
   a[row][col]=false;

   // if the input is correct only on of this moves will be valid
   // try each of them and see which move we can make
   if(col - 1 >= 0 && a[row][col-1]) { left(); travel(a, row, col-1, finalRow, finalCol)};
   if(col + 1 < 8 && a[row][col+1]) { right(); travel(a, row,col+1, finalRow, finalCol)};
   if(row - 1 >= 0 && a[row-1][col]) { up(); travel(a, row-1, col, finalRow, finalCol)};
   if(row + 1 < 11 && a[row+1][col]) { down(); travel(a, row+1,col, finalRow, finalCol)};
}
```